# Why is memory leaking with MemoryCache C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, memorycache

I had an issue with memory leaks. After some investigation, I finally found a source. I managed to fix the issue, but I don't really understand why it works. It seems like some garbage collector thing, I understand it doesn't free memory allocated for result collection, but I don't really understand well why.

Disclamer: It isn't a "real" code.

```
Startup.cs

services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>();
services.AddScoped<ICacheProvider, CacheProvider>();
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
services.RegisterHttpClient<IHttpClient, HttpClient>();


MyService.cs

await _cacheProvider.GetMeData(ids, token);
```

```
CacheProvider.cs WITH MEMORY LEAK

public async Task<Data[]> GetMeData(long[] ids, CancellationToken token)
{
 List<Data> resultCollection = new();
 List<long> toRequest = new();
 foreach(var id in ids) 
 {
  if(_memoryCache.TryGet(id, out value))
  {
   resultCollection.Add(value);
  }
  else
  {
   toRequest.Add(id);
  }
 }

 var requestedData = await _httpClient.Request(toRequest, token);

 resultCollection.AddRange(requestedData); // <------

 foreach(d in requestedData)
  _memoryCache.Set(d.Id, d, _absoluteExpiration);

 return resultCollection. ToArray();
}
```

```
CacheProvider.cs WITHOUT MEMORY LEAK

public async Task<Data[]> GetMeData(long[] ids, CancellationToken token)
{
 List<Data> resultCollection = new();
 List<long> toRequest = new();

 foreach(var id in ids) 
 {
  if(_memoryCache.TryGet(id, out value))
  {
   resultCollection.Add(value);
  }
  else
  {
   toRequest.Add(id);
  }
 }

 var requestedData = await _httpClient.Request(toRequest, token);

 foreach(d in requestedData)
  resultCollection.Add(_memoryCache.Set(d.Id, d, _absoluteExpiration));  // <------

 return resultCollection. ToArray();
}
```

Can someone pls explain why this change removes memory leak? I have a theory, but...

Comment: This code makes no sense. For example, you are calling `_memoryCache.Set` with the same key for multiple values. Also `_memoryCache.Set` doesn't return a value so the "fixed" version doesn't even compile. This clearly isn't actual code.

Comment: Where is `key`coming from in the first place?

Comment: And the method is claiming to be async, but does nothing async?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't thought it could bé important. I've fixed the questions in the "code". I hope it's clearer now